# how to insert std::vector elements into an std::unordered_map using emplace

Tags: c++

How to insert elements of an `std::vector` as value into an `std::unordered_map` using `emplace` and `std::piecewise_construct`. This is my sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> umap;
    umap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple("abc"), std::forward_as_tuple({ 1, 2, 3, 4 }));
}
```

I'm getting the below error

```
error: too many arguments to function 'constexpr std::tuple<_Elements&& ...> std::forward_as_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {}]'
```

Answer (score 5):

The expression

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

Has no implicit type.    If you want it to be an initializer list (for constructing a vector) you may write it as

```
std::initializer_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler can't know you want to construct a `std::vector<int>` from the initializer list you pass to the last `std::forward_as_tuple` (namely `{ 1,2,3,4 }`).

You have to explicitly tell it:

```
std::forward_as_tuple(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 })
```

or, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17),

```
std::forward_as_tuple(std::vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4 })
```

Comment: does it create a temporary `std::vector` before actually inserting into `std::unordered_map`? just a performance concern

Comment: @Harry Yes, it creates a temporary which will be moved into the map.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using `std::piecewise_construct`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Partially, yes. You'll still be able to construct the `std::string` in-place.